# Video streaming by getting bytes in buffer storage and play it while downloading in android

Tags: android, video

I want to play video in android by the following requirements

Video file to be stored in temporary buffer storage

while file storing in buffer area should play

after completing the video playing the buffer area should be cleared.

any help welcomed.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? @KarthikeyanVe

Comment: Yes. But some suggested that this method not streaming. So I decided to make it chunk files. If you have any idea about chunk files and play the video please .....

Comment: I'm sort of stuck with the same problem, I wanted to see if you figured it out.. @KarthikeyanVe

Comment: Has anyone solved it?